# confused on the combination of Head ref and git rebase --interactive

Tags: git

Let's say we have following workflow:

```
             master
               |
A -> B -> C -> D
```

let's say I select the most 3 recent commits (B, C, D) to perform some actions e.g squash.

so the command is

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

But isn't that `HEAD~3` corresponds to commit `A` (since HEAD~0 is `D`).

Isn't that more sensible to use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

?
My guess is users might want to squash `B`, so `A` has to be included to achieve that, but isn't that more sensible that Git can be designed to include one extra oldest commit automatically?

Comment: See the difference between `git log HEAD~2..` and `git log HEAD~3..` (the dots are important, `HEAD~2..` means `HEAD~2..HEAD`)

Comment: Half-open intervals are common in many mathematical operations, whether one writes them as `(A, B]` or `]A, B]` or—as Git does—`A..B`. Git's notation does leave something to be desired since it's not clear which edge is excluded and which edge is included, but one can get used to anything as long as it is consistent.

Comment: One might argue that Git should just consistently used closed intervals, `[A,B]` in more typical notation. Mercurial, in fact, *does* do this. It turns out to be *less convenient* because it then becomes hard to exclude the left-side revision when necessary. Because the directed graph of commits has all of its arcs pointing "backwards" (to previous commits), it's easy to add the left-side edge back: just write `A~..B`. In your case you could write `HEAD~2~`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History):

> You must indicate how far back you want to rewrite commits by telling
>   the command which commit to rebase onto.
>
> For example, if you want to
>   change the last three commit messages, or any of the commit messages
>   in that group, you supply as an argument to `git rebase -i` the parent
>   of the last commit you want to edit, which is `HEAD~2^` or `HEAD~3`. It
>   may be easier to remember the `~3` because you’re trying to edit the
>   last three commits, but keep in mind that you’re actually designating
>   four commits ago, the parent of the last commit you want to edit: